# "connection failed. activation of network connection failed" mobile broadband ubuntu

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, mobile-broadband

I have spent some time looking for a solution, but I just cannot find one taht suits my situation.
I have a toshiba notebook with a built-in sim card. Running Ubuntu 18.04 with little hiccups.

About 3 weeks ago, I was able to connect to the internet using the built-in sim card, however, it all of a sudden stopped one morning.
When I click on Connect, or switch the mobile data to On, the system attempts to connect for a while, then pops up with the following error:

Connection Failed. Activation of network connection failed"

I believed that this was due to the sim card, so I have replaced it, and am now using one that worked 100% in the past with the same device. Still having the same issue.

I have edited the connection settings, cleared them totally, created new ones, but still no success for now.

I am a newbie to Ubuntu,so any guidance in resolving this would be great.

Thank you

Comment: I have restarted the machine and inserted the older card. It asked me for the sim pin before logging in, and that is working :)
I will test the second current SIM.

Answer (score 0):

Check the SIM Card pins... just because it isn't obvious, make sure they are inputted in the connection configuration screen at the bottom.